# Highlight cell based on custom formula of conditional formatting

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, max, google-sheets-formula, sequence

I will input numbers serially but not in consecutive cells, it would be random like this:
[image]
I want to highlight numbers from where the serial number is broken as shown (Since number 17 is missing so number 18 onwards all number are highlighted)

Please help me with a custom formula for the conditional formatting of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this new approach:

```
=REGEXMATCH(A2&"", INDEX(TEXTJOIN("|", 1, "×",
 SORT(IFERROR(1/(1/((IFERROR(SORT(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(IFERROR(SPLIT(A$2:A, ",")))))<>
 SEQUENCE(MAX(FLATTEN(IFERROR(SPLIT(A$2:A, ","))))), TRUE))*
 SEQUENCE(MAX(FLATTEN(IFERROR(SPLIT(A$2:A, ",")))))))), 1, 0))))
```

[image]

Comment: This formula highlights the whole column if the last number is in the cell with multiple values (https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZz1K.png)

Comment: @AashitGarodia fixed. try now

Comment: Thanks, If I drag and move any row to the 2nd row , the conditional formatting formula automatically changes A$2:$A to A$3:$A. Is there any way I could freely move rows without the affecting the formula?

Comment: @AashitGarodia you can change `A$2:A` to `INDIRECT("A2:A")`

Comment: if I use this `INDIRECT("A2:A")` then even on changing columns order (say this column A becomes B) this formula remains the same, so I have to manually change Letter A to B in the formula. Any chance this happens automatically?

Comment: @take a look into ADDRESS you can try something like: `INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,COLUMN(A2),4)&":"&ADDRESS(ROWS(A:A),COLUMN(A2),4))`

Comment: Damn, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=A2>INDEX(MAX(IFERROR((SEQUENCE(MAX(A$2:A))=SORT(A$2:A))*SEQUENCE(MAX(A$2:A)))))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A2&"", "\d+,?")*1>INDEX(MAX(IFERROR((SEQUENCE(MAX(A$2:A))=
 SORT(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(SPLIT(A$2:A, ",")))))*SEQUENCE(MAX(A$2:A)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Hii, long time no see. Hope you remember me?

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Can you please explain me the formula, I only understood the SORT(A$2:A) & =sequence(MAX(A$2:A)) rest I didn't understand anything!

Comment: Okay I understood you used INDEX as an ArrayFormula. Thanks!

Comment: @AashitGarodia we take a sequence of 20 numbers and compare/match it to sorted values of A column. if there is a match we return the number and from this whole matched array we take the max number and compare it (>) to A column values

Comment: Hi, I understood this thank you so much!, but there are two problems I am facing: `(1)` Some time same number is repeated more than once (I found the solution of using Unique)  `(2)` Some time I input 2 or 3 different numbers in one cell itself like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSkDg.png is there any way this could be treated as 3 different input numbers?

Comment: I can't find the solution for the `(2)` part. How can I edit the formula such that it interprets those 3 values as 3 different input & so the cell actually doesn't get highlight?

Comment: @AashitGarodia answer updated

Comment: This is really crazy works exactly as I wanted, I understand everything except the significance of `*1` in the formula. To understand it I wrote the formula to each cells and it shows error on the cell with 3 inputs saying: Error
Function MULTIPLY parameter 1 expects number values. But '42,' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number. Please explain me the significance of `*1`

Comment: @AashitGarodia regex is able to work only with text strings so for example we need to convert numeric `5` to `5&""` to make sure its plain text. then to convert `5&""` to number again we multiply it by 1 like:  `(5&"")*1` coz we need to compare numeric value with another numeric value using `>`

Comment: So how come in cell it throws an error, but on the other hand works in conditional formatting?

Comment: @AashitGarodia there are some differences when it comes to CF and regular in-cell formula syntaxes.

Comment: Instead of `SEQUENCE(MAX(A$2:A))` shouldn't we use `SEQUENCE(MAX(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(IFERROR(SPLIT(F$2:F, ",",0))))))` so that if the maximum number is present with other numbers in the same cell it takes it into consideration. Now when I modify the formula, the index part of the formula gives me the right value but doesn't work in conditional formatting, i.e. Cells with multiple numbers doesn't get highlight. Please check out this Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lkULK3PHFO2oYeWeKAjeDAeiJoYBHN6LXziGdke4TVo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you please help with this?

Comment: @AashitGarodia try the alternative answer